# awk compare three files and merge output

Tags: awk

I have 3 files 1.csv and 2.csv and 3.csv

1.csv

```
TELECOM_DEVELOPMENT_AFGHANISTAN_COMPANY,AFGHANISTAN,Alphanumeric_A_MSISDN_blocking,1  
CABLE&WIRELESS_BARBADOS,BARBADOS,Alphanumeric_A_MSISDN_blocking,791  
SIMINN_ICELAND_TELECOM,ICELAND,Alphanumeric_A_MSISDN_blocking,109373  
CABLE&WIRELESS_SEYCHELLES,SEYCHELLES,Alphanumeric_A_MSISDN_blocking,2  
CABLE&WIRELESS_JAMAICA,JAMAICA,Alphanumeric_A_MSISDN_blocking,85
```

2.csv

```
SIMINN_ICELAND_TELECOM,ICELAND,SPAM_CHAIN_SMS_REJECT(Spam_Detection_and_Blocking),7795  
CABLE&WIRELESS_SEYCHELLES,SEYCHELLES,SPAM_CHAIN_SMS_REJECT(Spam_Detection_and_Blocking),638
```

3.csv:

```
TELECOM_DEVELOPMENT_AFGHANISTAN_COMPANY,AFGHANISTAN,Calling_Party_Address_Blocking,79  
CABLE&WIRELESS_BARBADOS,BARBADOS,Calling_Party_Address_Blocking,30  
MOBILKOM_LIECHTENSTEIN,LIECHTENSTEIN,Calling_Party_Address_Blocking,6
SYNIVERSE_ANSI,UNITED_STATES,Calling_Party_Address_Blocking,12
```

I want to merge files so that it will print output file as below

```
TELECOM_DEVELOPMENT_AFGHANISTAN_COMPANY,AFGHANISTAN,Alphanumeric_A_MSISDN_blocking,1,NA,NA,Calling_Party_Address_Blocking,79
CABLE&WIRELESS_BARBADOS,BARBADOS,Alphanumeric_A_MSISDN_blocking,791,NA,NA,Calling_Party_Address_Blocking,30
SIMINN_ICELAND_TELECOM,ICELAND,Alphanumeric_A_MSISDN_blocking,109373,SPAM_CHAIN_SMS_REJECT(Spam_Detection_and_Blocking),7795,NA,NA
CABLE&WIRELESS_SEYCHELLES,SEYCHELLES,Alphanumeric_A_MSISDN_blocking,2,SPAM_CHAIN_SMS_REJECT(Spam_Detection_and_Blocking),638,NA,NA
CABLE&WIRELESS_JAMAICA,JAMAICA,Alphanumeric_A_MSISDN_blocking,85,NA,NA,NA,NA 
MOBILKOM_LIECHTENSTEIN,LIECHTENSTEIN,NA,NA,NA,NA,Calling_Party_Address_Blocking,6
SYNIVERSE_ANSI,UNITED_STATES,NA,NA,NA,NA,Calling_Party_Address_Blocking,12
```

My Script:

```
awk ' BEGIN { FS = OFS ="," } 
FNR==NR {
    a[$1 FS $2] = $3 FS $4; 
    next
} 
{
    print $0, (($1 FS $2) in a?a[$1 FS $2]:"NA,NA")
    delete a[$1 FS $2]
}
END {
    for(left in a) print left,"NA,NA", a[left]
}' 1.csv 2.csv 3.csv
```

Output:

```
SIMINN_ICELAND_TELECOM,ICELAND,SPAM_CHAIN_SMS_REJECT(Spam_Detection_and_Blocking),7795,Alphanumeric_A_MSISDN_blocking,109373  
CABLE&WIRELESS_SEYCHELLES,SEYCHELLES,SPAM_CHAIN_SMS_REJECT(Spam_Detection_and_Blocking),638,Alphanumeric_A_MSISDN_blocking,2  
TELECOM_DEVELOPMENT_AFGHANISTAN_COMPANY,AFGHANISTAN,Calling_Party_Address_Blocking,79,Alphanumeric_A_MSISDN_blocking,1  
CABLE&WIRELESS_BARBADOS,BARBADOS,Calling_Party_Address_Blocking,30,Alphanumeric_A_MSISDN_blocking,791  
MOBILKOM_LIECHTENSTEIN,LIECHTENSTEIN,Calling_Party_Address_Blocking,6,NA,NA  
SYNIVERSE_ANSI,UNITED_STATES,Calling_Party_Address_Blocking,12,NA,NA  
CABLE&WIRELESS_JAMAICA,JAMAICA,NA,NA,Alphanumeric_A_MSISDN_blocking,85
```

As you can see my output is mismanaged, please suggest solution.

Comment: I did suggest that you add a few more lines of your file but it's still important that you show your original attempt and describe clearly what you are trying to do, rather than rely on people working it out.

Comment: @TomFenech as i had mentioned earlier my first attempt was to merge two files and that was successful how ever now when i am trying to merge 3 files its not working out. re adding my awk script in question for your reference. please suggest where i am wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how you could do it:

```
BEGIN { FS = "," }

FNR==1 { ++file }

{
    a[$1,$2,file] = $3 FS $4
    ++seen[$1,$2]
}

END {
    for (j in seen) {
        split(j, b, SUBSEP)
        s = b[1] FS b[2]
        for (i=1; i<=file; ++i) {
            s = s FS (j SUBSEP i in a ? a[j,i] : "NA" FS "NA")
        }
        print s
    }
}
```

Previously it looked like 1.csv was the master record and that 2.csv and 3.csv only contained additional data for existing records.

Every time a new file begins, increment the `file` counter. Add every record found to the array `a`, using first two columns and the file counter as a key. Add the first two columns to the `seen` array so the full list of keys is known.

In the end block, loop through the seen array. Merge together each record, using "NA" if the part of the record is missing.

Testing it out:

```
$ awk -f merge.awk 1.csv 2.csv 3.csv 
SYNIVERSE_ANSI,UNITED_STATES,NA,NA,NA,NA,Calling_Party_Address_Blocking,12
TELECOM_DEVELOPMENT_AFGHANISTAN_COMPANY,AFGHANISTAN,Alphanumeric_A_MSISDN_blocking,1,NA,NA,Calling_Party_Address_Blocking,79
MOBILKOM_LIECHTENSTEIN,LIECHTENSTEIN,NA,NA,NA,NA,Calling_Party_Address_Blocking,6
CABLE&WIRELESS_JAMAICA,JAMAICA,Alphanumeric_A_MSISDN_blocking,85,NA,NA,NA,NA
SIMINN_ICELAND_TELECOM,ICELAND,Alphanumeric_A_MSISDN_blocking,109373,SPAM_CHAIN_SMS_REJECT(Spam_Detection_and_Blocking),7795,NA,NA
CABLE&WIRELESS_BARBADOS,BARBADOS,Alphanumeric_A_MSISDN_blocking,791,NA,NA,Calling_Party_Address_Blocking,30
CABLE&WIRELESS_SEYCHELLES,SEYCHELLES,Alphanumeric_A_MSISDN_blocking,2,SPAM_CHAIN_SMS_REJECT(Spam_Detection_and_Blocking),638,NA,NA
```

Note that the ordering of the output has changed because it depends on the order in which the keys appear in `seen`. To impose a strict order would be an additional step and I'm not sure whether it is required.

Comment: I tried your command on my files but not all the times calling in coming in last two columns, sometimes its in 3rd and 4th column and sometimes in 5th and 6th. can i attach my source files here ?

Comment: It would be better if you just added a few more lines to the samples in your question so that it showed all the possibilities.

Comment: I have edited my question with more lines, now please help to check the output with output of above awk script.

Comment: any idea how can we do this ?

Comment: @user3898409 I've updated my code to reflect the changes in your question. It does what you want now.

Comment: as you can see in my awk script I have used "for(left in a) print left,"NA,0", a[left]" that was for case where column one and two of file one are not matched with column 1 and 2 of file two then it prints only file 1 details and na,na for file 2.
I see we are not having this option in your code, can we also add this in your code, and how ?

Comment: @user3898409 I'm sorry, I don't understand what you're asking. I've already spent a fair amount of my time writing code to answer your first question and then updated it so it works for your more complicated case. I've also tried to explain my approach to make it clear what I've done. You've already accepted an answer, which suggests that your problem is solved.

Comment: yes I have accepted your answer and given script is merging files but later i found that after merging some data of file2 and file3 is missing from output file. I will ask this question in different post with proper explanation.

Comment: @user3898409 rather than creating a new question and abandoning this one, I recommend that you work on editing this question to make it as clear as possible. My code works for the example you have provided, so if you have some examples different data that it doesn't work for, you should include it in your question. By the way, you actually accepted a different answer to mine. That's not a problem but it gives the impression that your problem is solved, so you shouldn't be asking for more help at this stage.

Comment: As suggested by you I have updated my question and this time the only change is in file 3.csv. I have 2 lines in end of file 3.csv. Now if i run provided awk scripts you can see these last two lines are not reflected in output. please add modify the script so that these two lines will also come in output. in my script to achive this I had added this : END {
    for(left in a) print left,"NA,0", a[left]
}' 1.csv 2.csv 3.csv; 
But no idea how to modify it in your script.

Comment: @user3898409 I have modified my answer so that it works for the new input. I would suggest that you add your attempts back into the question to make it clear to others what you are trying to do and what you have tried so far. Don't forget to upvote answers you find useful and accept your favourite answer to show your appreciation for the help that we have provided you.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
BEGIN { FS = "," }
function include_missing(  key) {
    append = ""
    for (i = field_count[file_index] - 2; i > 0; --i) {
        append = append ",NA"
    }
    for (i = 1; i <= k; ++i) {
        key = keys[i]
        if (validity[key] < file_index) {
            data[key] = data[key] append
            ++validity[key]
        }
    }
}
{
    sub(/[ \t\r]*$/, "")
    key = $1 FS $2
    if (FNR == 1) {
        if (file_index) {
            include_missing()
        }
        field_count[++file_index] = NF
    }
    if (file_index == 1) {
        keys[++k] = key
    }
    ++validity[key]
    data[key] = data[key] substr($0, length(key) + 1)
}
END {
    include_missing()
    for (i = 1; i <= k; ++i) {
        key = keys[i]
        print key data[key]
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
awk -f script.awk file1 file2 fil3
```

Output:

```
TELECOM_DEVELOPMENT_AFGHANISTAN_COMPANY,AFGHANISTAN,Alphanumeric_A_MSISDN_blocking,1,NA,NA,Calling_Party_Address_Blocking,79
CABLE&WIRELESS_BARBADOS,BARBADOS,Alphanumeric_A_MSISDN_blocking,791,NA,NA,Calling_Party_Address_Blocking,30
SIMINN_ICELAND_TELECOM,ICELAND,Alphanumeric_A_MSISDN_blocking,109373,SPAM_CHAIN_SMS_REJECT(Spam_Detection_and_Blocking),7795,Calling_Party_Address_Blocking,1160
CABLE&WIRELESS_SEYCHELLES,SEYCHELLES,Alphanumeric_A_MSISDN_blocking,2,SPAM_CHAIN_SMS_REJECT(Spam_Detection_and_Blocking),638,NA,NA
CABLE&WIRELESS_JAMAICA,JAMAICA,Alphanumeric_A_MSISDN_blocking,85,NA,NA,Calling_Party_Address_Blocking,1
```

With GNU Awk it can also be simpler:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
BEGIN { FS = "," }
{
    sub(/[ \t\r]*$/, "")
    key = $1 FS $2
    if (ARGIND == 1) {
        keys[++k] = key
    }
    ++validity[key]
    data[key] = data[key] substr($0, length(key) + 1)
}
ENDFILE {
    append = ""
    for (i = NF - 2; i > 0; --i) {
        append = append ",NA"
    }
    for (i = 1; i <= k; ++i) {
        key = keys[i]
        if (validity[key] < ARGIND) {
            data[key] = data[key] append
            ++validity[key]
        }
    }
}
END {
    for (i = 1; i <= k; ++i) {
        key = keys[i]
        print key data[key]
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
gawk -f script.awk file1 file2 file3
```

Comment: you missed NA,NA part. please re suggest the answer as per conditions mentioned in my question. as per your script file 2 and file 3 are printed in same column and no "NA" is printed for non matching cases.